# Estimate of Hits / Visits / Uniques in order to fall within a given Alexa Tier?

Tags: traffic, ranking, alexa

I was wondering if anyone could offer up rough estimates that could tell me how many hits a day move you into a given Alexa rank ?

- Top     5,000
- Top    10,000
- Top    50,000
- Top   100,000
- Top   500,000
- Top 1,000,000

I know this is incredibly subjective and thus the broad brush strokes with the number ranges... *BUT* I've got a site currently ranked just over 1.2M worldwide and over 500k in the USA (http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/fstr.net)

Pretty cool for something hand-built on weekends (pat self on back)

I was applying to an ad-platform and was told that their program doesn't accept webmasters who have an Alexa rank of greater than 100,000.  (Time to take back that pat on the back I guess).

I know that my hits in the last 30 days are somewhere on the order of 15,000 uniques and 20,000 pageviews.  So I'm wondering how much harder do I have to work to achieve my next "goals"?

I'd like to break into the top million, then re-evaluate from there.  It'd be nice to know what those targets translate into (very roughly of course).

I imagine that alexa ranks and tiers become very much exponential as you move up the ranks, but even hearing annecdotal evidence from other webmasters would be really useful to me.

(ie: I have a site that is ranked X and it got Y hits in the last 30 days)

Comment: Alexa measures traffic by users who uses the Alexa toolbar. Make sure you download it yourself and go to your site regularly. Our website only has less than 50 clicks per day and because we all use Alexa tool bar, it's ranking has been decreasing dramatically from 1 million + to now 646,000 within 2 months.

Comment: Well, here (http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm) is described a way to make a traffic estimation based on the alexa rank.  Basically, the author has offered an exponential function, not linear or polynomial.
There is also a web service which aggregated alexa ranks + real data and made the calculations: http://www.alexarank2traffic.com/
I checked it, and for 80% of the websites the results are very satisfying. Still, there is 20% of (possibly, manipulated by webmasters) incorrect data (the estimated traffic is much higher than in reality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a professional web developer I've built and hosted many sites, including personal projects. Here is a range of data from different sites that should help you. Numbers are *per month* - specifically, the last 30 days from Google Analytics - and rounded to the nearest 100.

1. 1,800 Visits, 10,800 Pageviews -- Alexa **#5,858,200**
2. 46,800 Visits, 143,800 Pageviews -- Alexa **#255,000**
3. 56,900 Visits, 106,900 Pageviews -- Alexa **#181,200**
4. 86,900 Visits, 184,400 Pageviews -- Alexa **#306,300**
5. 684,500 Visits, 6,267,300 Pageviews -- Alexa **#74,400**

You can at least see that Alexa's data is not all that reliable since #4 is a bit of an anomaly. Its traffic has dropped in the last couple of months but even extrapolating last week's data to the 30-day range, it still has more visits than #3.

It should also be noted that Alexa guesses website ranks based on people with the Alexa toolbar installed. This means firstly that any site outside the top 100,000 is not measured accurately (as Alexa state themselves). Second, I believe it's possible to fudge the results yourself by installing the toolbar and visiting your own site regularly.

Comment: I have got a site ranked 329xxx worldwide.  (3 lac 29 thousand and something). It has about 2000 visits and 6000 pageviews per month. The numbers and stats have been steady for a few months now. So much for Alexa rankings. (believe me, rankings beyond 100K should just be ignored completely).

Answer (score 1):

I'm involved with a site that is ranked 94,000-ish in Alexa, and they've got 180,000 uniques in the past 30 days, and 800,000 pageviews.

However, this site is outside the US and gets traffic mostly from outside the US. We believe that the demographics of Alexa toolbar users mean that this site has a lower Alexa position than if it were a US site with a lot of traffic originating from the US.

Sorry, i can't name the site as it belongs to a client, and they may not want me to publish traffic figures.

Answer (score 1):

I Want to add to the above statements from my Personal and own experience, Alexa ranking is not that reliable to determine whether your site is doing good or not

Comment: While that's true in terms of asking the question "am I the most popular site in the world?" the Alexa rank has certain 'intrinsic value' as a measure of the site's potential for monetization.  In terms of a very concrete example, I applied to an advertiser's program who rejected me because I was less than 100,000k in Alexa rank.  I also like it as a "goal to work for" improving in Alexa feels like an external validation of a recognizable success measure (real or not it makes me feel good)  :D

Answer (score 0):

One of my sites has had an Alexa rank floating around the 900,000 to 1,100,000 mark for a while now and it gets around 50,000 visitors a month.  The site is outside the US.

My reason for giving this data is that it is rather different to the equivalent data shown in DisgruntledGoat's answer.

....all of which shows how difficult it is to project traffic from an Alexa rank.