# Finding estimated traffic to a website

Tags: analytics, visitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Estimate of Hits / Visits / Uniques in order to fall within a given Alexa Tier?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7338/estimate-of-hits-visits-uniques-in-order-to-fall-within-a-given-alexa-tier)

I remember using a tool in the past that did this, but can't remember what it was. Alexa.com/siteinfo doesn't seem to give estimates in user numbers (or maybe I'm not looking in the right place). It just gives rank. Is there a way to convert that rank to an estimate visitor number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not a way to use Alexa to determine how many visitors a website has. If you don't have access to their log files or whichever analytics program they're using how do you expect any website to estimate traffic?

It's anyone's guess how much traffic a website receives. But unless you have access to their analytics or raw access logs you shouldn't assume any estimates are correct.

Who cares where they rank what if they are spending large amounts of money on TV ads in a particular city and getting lots of direct traffic. Would anyone be able to account for that? Or what about paid ads, or affiliate ads? How about referral traffic?

Don't even bother trying to figure it out or find a site that claims to have estimates for another websites traffic. It's not going to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that you can use to estimate traffic for a website. However, none of them are completely accurate. Generally speaking, they are best used to measure trends. For example, you can see the seasonality of different websites (e.g. if their traffic peaks at Christmas). You can also see if traffic is trending up or down. This all said, generally speaking, if these tools all indicate that a website has 1M visitors or more, it is definitely a high-traffic website. Conversely, if they all indicate that the website has only a few hundred visitors per month, it is most likely a low-traffic website. To answer your question, try these tools:

- http://www.compete.com
- http://www.quantcast.com
- http://www.spyfu.com (top left of screen, where it compares ppc to seo)
- http://www.semrush.com (bottom left of screen, where it estimates SE traffic)

Comment: You cant see if a websites traffic peaks at Christmas using any of the sites below. The only thing you can accurately see is if a site is running more than usual PPC ads. You can't see if traffic is trending up or down unless you have access to their log files. The sites have no way to know if a site has 1M visitors see my answer direct traffic, tv, radio, affiliate traffic has nothing to do with their organic rankings. Which you still can't estimate traffic based off of. As some of us know what Google estimates in search volume rarely comes close to equaling organic traffic visits.